# FFC Flex PCB Flat Connector for Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Tags: raspberry-pi, connector, ffc, barcode

I have bought a barcode scanner online (promised to be specific for Raspberry Pi 3 with USB interface) but its cable does not have any connector and is just a flat cable with numbers as `AWM 20624 VW-1 80c 60v`.

I am not that much familiar with electrical modules and more a programmer and do not know what type of connector I need to connect it to the camera port of Raspberry Pi.

The cable itself has 12 pins as I can count where the port on Raspberry Pi seems to have 22 pins. If I get a connector like [this](https://www.globalsources.com/gsol/I/Flat-cable/p/sm/1162516696.htm#1162516696) is there an adapter/converter for it.

Or am I going totally wrong and it should not be connected to camera port?

Comment: You might want to consider asking on [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks, I did not know even that exists :)

Comment: USB devices get connected to USB ports, not specialized camera ports.  It sounds like the item you bought is missing pieces unless it was specifically sold has as its claimed USB interface being embedded in another cable  you should send it back or pursue a refund from the payment processor.

Comment: As the question here is really about the mystery/incomplete scanner, there's no point in asking this on the pi site or migrating it.  That there is no USB interface on the pi's camera connector is widely known.